# PHP Version on Plesk and CentOS are different?

Tags: php, linux, centos, plesk, versions

I am quite new to Linux servers, but I found something strange to me and maybe someone can give a proper explanation for this:
In PLESK Admin Panel on "Hosting Settings" for my domain the PHP version is 5.6.
But when I access via SSH to my server and type php -v it says that I have version 5.4. Why the information is different and which one is the real?

Comment: The CLI / mod_php / php-fpm etc are all separate SAPIs, so CLI can be a different version from the others. So yes, it is real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run php -v via ssh session, you run system or OS vendor's php. Plesk PHPs for hosting are located in /opt/plesk/php/X.X/bin/php where X.X is version of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this better option
ssh as root user and use this commands one by one.

```
mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php.backup
mv /usr/bin/php-cgi /usr/bin/php-cgi.backup

ln -s /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php /usr/bin/php
ln -s /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php-cgi /usr/bin/php-cgi
```